# Blender Python How to convert a mesh with materials to vertex colors?

Tags: python, colors, blender, vertex

I have imported objects with meshes, each having over 50 different materials, which display only a unique color, so I want get rid of the materials and use vertex colors.

That means, each vertex of a face that has a particular material assigned will be colored to the materials main color.

But I have issues to convert this. I cant get the faces that a material uses. This is what I have so far:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:       #support multiple selection
    if obj.type == 'MESH':                  #color only if mesh exists

        mesh = bpy.context.object.data                  
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(mesh) 

        materials = bpy.data.materials      #get current meshs materials

        for index in range(len(materials)):         #get corresponding faces of material 

            for face in bm.faces:      
                if face.material_index == index: #select face that matches current material
                    face.select = True

                    for L in face.loops:
                        L[bm.loops.layers.color.active] = materials[index].diffuse_color

       # bpy.data.materials = [] #remove all materials from material tab

        bm.to_mesh(mesh) #Assign new mesh from bmesh
        bm.free()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `material_index` is index within material slots, not in global `bpy.data.materials`, and your writing to vertex colours in loops doesn't look fine. Take a look at `uv_bake_texture_to_vcols` script (bundled with blender) as it does something similar. Or just bake to vertex colours, it is a standard blender feature that requires no python code.